# How to show values from table without using Entities?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to do "sql interpreter" in my web-app, only for CRUD. Everything work fine, I am using method prepareStatement() to execute query. But I have problem with operation select :

When I use the select operation only for 1 field, then parsing to a string gives a fairly good result:

```
for(String x: resultList){
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Is there any way to execute:

> SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3  FROM table;

and print result in console, with some neat form **without use Entites?**

Well if it isn't possible, is there any way to generate entity "on the fly"? I mean generate Entities using java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a native query and explicitly specify which columns you want to select:

```
String sql = "SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM table";
Query q = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
List<Object[]> results = q.getResultList();

for (Object[] r : results) {
    System.out.println("(field_1, field_2, field_3) = (" + r[0] + ", " + r[1] + ", " + r[2] + ")");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### With Spring Data JPA Projections

If you already use some entities and Spring Repository then you can add this code to one of them. Thanks [Spring Data JPA Projections](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-projections).

```java
public interface SomeEntityRepository extends Repository<SomeEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM table", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TableDto> getFromTable();
}
```

Where `TableDto`:

```java
public interface TableDto{
    Long getField_1();
    String getField_2();
    String getField_3();
}
```

#### With Spring JdbcTemplate

Or use Spring [JdbcTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate#3-mapping-query-results-to-java-object):

```java
String query = "SELECT field_1, field_2, field_3 FROM table where id = ?";
List<TableDto> resluts = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
  query, new Object[] { id }, new TableDtoRowMapper());
```

```java
public class TableDtoRowMapper implements RowMapper<TableDto> {
    @Override
    public TableDtomapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        TableDto dto = new TableDto();

        dto.setField_1(rs.getString("field_1"));
        dto.setField_2(rs.getString("field_2"));
        dto.setField_3(rs.getString("field_3"));

        return dto;
    }
}
```

In this example `TableDto` is real class with getters and setters.